# Archiva vs artifactory

Tags: apache, artifactory, archiva

I am doing some research on Apache Archiva and Artifactory. So, actually i am not finding exact information about apache archiva and artifactory supporting following features or not:

```
1) load balancing
2) Nuget  
3) Redhat and CentOs
4) Ease of Backup and disaster recovery 
5) LDAP mapping to local defined users.
```

So, please tell does all these features are supported by apache archiva and artifactory? It will be of great help.

Answer (score 9):

A good place to start will be the [Binary Repository Manager Feature Matrix](https://binary-repositories-comparison.github.io/) which contains highly detailed comparison of Artifactory, Archiva and Nexus.

Comment: Looks like it's too biased to `artifactory`!